# Can someone help me with rename tool?

Tags: linux, rename

I have to rename a bunch of files with this structure (it is a serie):
**SSEE_SerieName_Episode.Name.With.Dots_[some_variables_qualities].mkv**

SS is season number like 03 and EE episode number like 08 (with leading zero).
Plex can't recognize it because of it's crappy name... So I would like to rename it like this:
s**SS**e**EE**_SerieName_Episode.Name.With.Dots.mkv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

- You are using the Perl rename command.
- The `Episode.Name.With.Dots` substring does not contain an underscore character.
- You want to remove the `_[some_variables_qualities]` substring.
- The substring above starts with an underscore character.

Then would you please try the following:

```
rename 's/(\d{2})(\d{2})(_SerieName_[^_]+)_.*\.mkv/s$1e$2$3.mkv/' *.mkv
```

It renames:

```
0102_SerieName_Episode.Name.With.Dots_[some_variables_qualities].mkv
```

as:

```
s01e02_SerieName_Episode.Name.With.Dots.mkv
```

Please modify the `_SerieName_` portion in the command above according to your real filenames.

Answer (score 2):

In [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you can use variable expansion.

```sh
for old in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_*.mkv ; do
    new=s${old:0:2}e${old:2}
    if [[ -e $new ]] ; then
        echo "Can't rename $old to $new: file already exists." >&2
    else
        mv "$old" "$new"
    fi
done
```

`${old:0:2}` means two characters from `$old` starting at position 0, `${old:2}` means all the characters from `$old` from position 2.